Trouble Intercepting CAPTCHA Parameters Using Selenium and JavaScript for 2Captcha
I am trying to intercept CAPTCHA parameters from a webpage using Selenium and JavaScript. My goal is to use the 2Captcha service to solve the turnstile CAPTCHA on ahrefs. The issue I'm facing is that the parameters are not being intercepted correctly.
Here is my setup:
Python: 3.x
Selenium: seleniumbase
Browser: Chrome (headless mode)
CAPTCHA solving service: 2Captcha

Code, based on https://2captcha.com/api-docs/cloudflare-turnstile
import json
import re
import requests
from seleniumbase import Driver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

proxy = "xxxxxx:xxxxxx@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx"  # YOUR_2CAPTCHA_PROXY
my_key = "KEY_HERE_API"

# Setting up an updated UserAgent
agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

# Configuring the web driver to work in headless mode
driver = Driver(uc=True, log_cdp=True, headless=True, no_sandbox=True, agent=agent, proxy=False)

# URL of the website protected by the Turnstile CAPTCHA
url = "https://ahrefs.com/es/backlink-checker?input=google.com"
driver.get(url)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(10)  # Increased wait time to ensure the page and Turnstile CAPTCHA are fully loaded

# Function to intercept CAPTCHA parameters using JavaScript
def intercept(driver):
    print("Executing JavaScript to intercept CAPTCHA parameters...")
    driver.execute_script("""
    console.clear = () => console.log('Console was cleared')
    console.log('Checking for Turnstile...')
    const i = setInterval(()=>{
        if (window.turnstile) {
            console.log('Turnstile loaded')
            clearInterval(i)
            window.turnstile.render = (a, b) => {
                console.log('Overriding render function')
                let params = {
                    sitekey: b.sitekey,
                    pageurl: window.location.href,
                    data: b.cData,
                    pagedata: b.chlPageData,
                    action: b.action,
                    userAgent: navigator.userAgent,
                    json: 1
                }
                console.log('intercepted-params:' + JSON.stringify(params))
                window.cfCallback = b.callback
                console.log('Render function overridden')
                return
            }
        }
    }, 50)
    """)
    time.sleep(10)  # Increased sleep time to ensure parameters are captured
    print("Retrieving browser logs for intercepted parameters...")
    logs = driver.get_log("browser")
    for log in logs:
        if log['level'] == 'INFO':
            print("Log entry:", log['message'])
            if "intercepted-params:" in log["message"]:
                log_entry = log["message"].encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
                match = re.search(r'"intercepted-params:({.*?})"', log_entry)
                if match:
                    json_string = match.group(1)
                    params = json.loads(json_string)
                    return params
    return None

params = intercept(driver)

if params is None:
    print("Failed to intercept CAPTCHA parameters.")
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
    exit(0)

print("Intercepted CAPTCHA parameters:", params)

data0 = {
    "key": my_key,
    "method": "turnstile",
    "sitekey": params["sitekey"],
    "action": params["action"],
    "data": params["data"],
    "pagedata": params["pagedata"],
    "useragent": params["userAgent"],
    "json": 1,
    "pageurl": params["pageurl"],
}
response = requests.post("https://2captcha.com/in.php", data=data0)
print("Request sent", response.text)
s = response.json()["request"]

while True:
    solu = requests.get(f"https://2captcha.com/res.php?key={my_key}&action=get&json=1&id={s}").json()
    if solu["request"] == "CAPCHA_NOT_READY":
        print(solu["request"])
        time.sleep(8)
    elif "ERROR" in solu["request"]:
        print(solu["request"])
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        exit(0)
    else:
        break

for key, value in solu.items():
    print(key, ": ", value)

solu = solu['request']
driver.execute_script(f"cfCallback('{solu}');")
time.sleep(5)

Logs and Observations:
The script prints "Checking for Turnstile..." and "Turnstile loaded," indicating that the Turnstile library is loaded.
However, the script fails to intercept the CAPTCHA parameters and prints "Failed to intercept CAPTCHA parameters."
Questions:
Why is the render function override not capturing the CAPTCHA parameters?
Is there a better way to intercept these parameters using Selenium and JavaScript?
Any other suggestions to improve the interception process?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

It doesn’t sound like your override function gets called (no sign of “Overriding render function“ in the logs).  I doubt that approach will work, there’s no good reason that turnstile would call an exposed function since it can keep its own internal reference to the original function.

It's based on https://2captcha.com/api-docs/cloudflare-turnstile

Has anyone succeeded using 2captcha?
